# The variable answer isn't assigned the value true

Tags: javascript, html, variables, boolean, variable-assignment

Can somebody help me to fix my problem, There is warning : "***It looks like the variable answer isn't assigned the value true.*** "

the variable answer is assigned the Boolean value of true.

i'm trying to fix but i couldn't do.

```
var multiplesOfEight = [8, 16, 24, 32, 40];


var answer = multiplesOfEight[answer] % 8 !== 0;
var answer = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < multiplesOfEight.length; i++) {
    if (i % 8 !== 0) {
      console.log("multiple of 8");
      console.log(i);
    } else {
      console.log("X");
      console.log(i);
    };
  };
};

answer();
```

and here is the output of my code:

```
X 
0 
multiple of 8 
1 
multiple of 8 
2 
multiple of 8 
3 
multiple of 8 
4
multiple of 8 
5
```

Thank you from now

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with your code. Could you post what output you _expect_ to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your variable answer when you define the function answer

That said, are you perhaps looking for something like

```
var multiplesOfEightCheck = [8, 16, 24, 32, 40];

multiplesOfEightCheck.forEach(function(e) { 
     if (e % 8) 
          console.log("X"); 
     else 
          console.log("Multiple of 8"); 
     console.log(e); 
})
```